# Label encoder gives error as "too many indices for array" for training set on only single row

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, encoding

I have a dataset and the variable is a string and it of one single row containing 5959 columns and I want to encode categorical data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train[:,0] = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train[:,0])
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
y_train = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(y_train).toarray()
```

The data should be categorized for further processing and analysis.

Comment: are you sure the error is not caused by `y_train[:, 0]`? 
can you provide stacktrace as well?

Comment: I removed it and it gives an error as too many indices for arrray